# ABE prevents me from entering a certain website

Tags: noscript

I am using ABE to limit the inclusion of scripts to those pages where I actually want to use them, e.g. youtube/google/maps stuff.

However, recently I am facing the problem that when I want to enter youtube.com, ABE blocks me from doing so. So currently I have to disable ABE, open youtube.com, re-enable ABE, and use youtube normally. Why can I not simply open the webpage youtube.com from a different page? What is wrong in my ABE settings?

```
Site .ytimg.com .youtube.com
Accept from .youtube.com
Deny
```

Comment: What’s with the NoScript tag? Are you perhaps referring no NoScript the entire time?

Comment: @DanielB ABE is a feature of NoScript. https://noscript.net/abe/